# Why don't bookshelves come with wall mounting screws included?

Tags: walls, safety, furniture

I was assembling an IKEA bookshelf, and one of the most important steps to ensure safety is the installation of the L-bracket to secure the bookshelf to the wall. All the parts, including the bracket and the screw for attachment onto the shelf, are included (see below). To my disappointment, however, the long mounting screw for attachment to the wall is evidently missing. So now, I find myself unable to complete the project due to the missing mounting screws.

I don't think this is a special case for the bookshelf or for IKEA. Why don't furniture manufacturers include wall mounting screws in the package for convenience?

[image: Assemby Instructions for IKEA bookshelf]

Source: https://www.ikea.com/us/en/assembly_instructions/billy-height-extension-unit__AA-982217-8_pub.pdf

Comment: I have a screws box which has a variety of screws and other fixings for use in situations like this - a few drywall, plastic rawlplugs for concrete in various sizes etc - a good addition if you plan to do projects as safety is paramount.

Comment: Many of them DO come with such screws, though rarely ones suitable for all possible situations...

Comment: @MikeBrockington The last IKEA piece I bought did come with one pair of screws, and 3 different kinds of wall anchors (for wood, drywall, and concrete).  Mind you I didn't use any of them because the furniture in question is a 3' high clothes dresser - nearly impossible to tip over unless you're *really* trying to.  It even has warnings to open only one drawer at a time to avoid tipping - I could open all 3 drawers while they're loaded with lead bricks and that thing still wouldn't tip, methinks they might be a tad over-cautious about this sort of thing.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman They might be "over-cautious" because they settled a $46 million lawsuit resulting from a tipped-over Ikea dresser (probably not loaded with bricks) crushing a child to death.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It depends on the use case. For example if a care home installs some IKEA furniture, it has a legal duty to ensure that the residents (who may be mentally disturbed, have dementia, etc) can not injure themselves by literally climbing up the walls. Does a 300-lb person opening the drawers and climbing up them like stair steps count as "really trying to tip the furniture over?" Not necessarily, if whoever injured themselves doing it has no legal mental competence to "deliberately" do anything!

Comment: @DanC I'm willing to bet that dresser was one of the taller ones.  It makes perfect sense for a 6' tall dresser/shelf to be mounted to the wall, but not a short one like this.  I think if you tried to climb up the drawers like steps, the first thing that would happen is your foot would knock the bottom right out of the drawer (it's just a thin piece of particle board attached with staples), and mounting it to the wall wouldn't stop that from happening.  (Lead bricks would probably do the same of course - mine just has clothes in it.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman There were actually [2 child deaths from Ikea dressers](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/customer-service/product-support/recalls/following-an-additional-child-fatality-ikea-recalls-29-million-malm-and-other-models-of-chests-pub4128a7af), one from a 30" tall dresser and one from a 48" tall dresser.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman multiple BrandX bookshelves I've bought over the last 16 years all came with a bracket and a long wood screw, along with IIRC screw into a wooden stud instructions.

Comment: They often do. What did IKEA say when you asked?

Comment: I have used bookcases for 54 years and have never mounted one to the wall. I have even stood some up back-to-back perpendicular to the wall because I needed to fit more books into the room. Disclaimer: Other than myself in the early years, there have been no small children with access to my bookcases in all that time.

Comment: @shoover Sure, I have many posessions that would pose no real danger to anyone l except that I _do_ have small children around.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

From the linked assembly instructions:

> Screw(s) and plug(s) for the wall are not included. Assess the
> suitability of the wall to ensure that it will withstand the forces
> generated. Use screw(s) and plug(s) suitable for your walls and the
> intended load. If you are uncertain, seek professional advice. Read
> and follow each step of the instruction carefully

If they included default hardware, customers would use it without thinking even in cases where it was not appropriate for their wall construction, presumably leading to a potential liability for Ikea. By not including any hardware for wall attachment, they put the liability on someone else to get the right kind of hardware for however the customer's wall is built.

This is some speculation about Ikea's reasons based on their instructions. I imagine the situation is similar for other furniture retailers.

Comment: Agreed, but it's also heavily a cost saving measure.  Plenty of other wall-mounted products (ie: VESA mounts, etc) will come with hardware suitable for a number of common wall constructions and directions for each.  Adding the extra hardware is just a cost.  Liability is just a cost.  Not including these *ostensibly* for liability reasons is really just another way of cutting costs and making things simpler for the manufacturer.

Comment: Ikea also recently [came out of a $46M lawsuit](https://www.dezeen.com/2020/01/13/ikea-settlement-recalled-malm-dresser/) and [recall](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/customer-service/product-support/recalls/following-an-additional-child-fatality-ikea-recalls-29-million-malm-and-other-models-of-chests-pub4128a7af) that prompted the addition of these wall-mount brackets to all of their dressers and drawers. Given that these were not part of the original furniture design and had to be added in afterwards we can also guess that Ikea did the minimum necessary to comply with whatever the courts ordered.

Comment: @J... Your point about cost is a good one which I should have mentioned. I suppose there are many coniderations invisible to the consumer which would factor in to Ikea's decision to include mounting screws for some products but not others.

Comment: Guys, I'm sure it's NOT a cost saving measure.  It would be an unmeasurably low cost to have the line add in a couple of screws or fasteners.

Comment: @Fattie It's not just the fasteners - it's the liability(ie: design and sign phase). I'd actually be curious to see if new (post-lawsuit) Ikea designs contain wall fasteners and whether all the back catalog just got brackets thrown in as as backpatch.  Ikea is also the one-mouse-button of the DIY world, and wall fasteners need at least a stud finder, and maybe a masonry bit and hammer drill...and maybe that's just too scary for an Ikea instruction booklet with no words...designed for people who own no tools.

Comment: @J... Im not too sure that its going to change all that much - I just put together a tonne of Billy bookcases with Oxberg doors (both purchased in 2020), and both the bookcases and doors came with wall restraint fixtures separately - however, I also in the same batch put together a bunch of Billy bookcases and Besta storage cabinets purchased around 2014, and they also all came with wall restraint fixtures (L-brackets for the Billy, through-back restraints for the Besta).  Some Ikea furniture has always had them included.

Comment: There is a rather large section in the instructions giving you a bracket to attach to the furniture, but there is still no fastener to attach to the surface, because this is different depending on whether it is dry-wall, wood, or concrete. You can't possibly have all the parts for all scenarios, and you actually need to know what you are doing to make it safe.

Comment: @J... yes, that's exactly right.  TBC I believe some folks were suggesting it is literally the cost of adding a screw to the packet; the cost of literallyf adding a screw to the packet is absolutely tiny, barely measurable.

Comment: @Fattie I guess the point is that the cost of adding a screw to a box has very little to do with the cost of the screw itself.

Comment: @J... They have updated all their instructions and it is very prominent if the furniture needs to be anchored. I've installed 4-5 shelves that are either designed as wall mounted or requires anchoring, and none of them includes the screw itself.

Comment: Though, if I understand the way these brackets work correctly, not much strength is needed - they keep the piece of furniture from ever being in a position where its weight could lever the anchors out of the wall ....

Answer (score 16):

While they are 100% sure what type and size of fastener is required for assembling the product, they have no control over the type of wall/support you are installing/fastening the product to (concrete, masonry, wood..etc). It may have recommendation in the instruction sheet, with the type and size indicated for varies types of support medium, and indicating whether they are included in the package or not. But, usually the furnished parts are list on the inventory sheet enclosed with the package. From that, you can tell if a part is to be provided but missing.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is that they sometimes don't include them by default because not everybody needs them, so omitting them would reduce cost (and waste).

The premise of "why don't they come with wall mounting screws included?" isn't true; *sometimes* they do.  If they don't, you can ask IKEA for wall mounting screws, which they will provide for free.

Answer (score 0):

Ikea, and other providers, have no clue as to what wall their bookcases (and other furniture) might be destined for. Several different constructions come to mind, each needing a different screw/fixing for the bracket. They *could* furnish all kinds of fixings, but then some customers would use an inappropriate one, and there could be legals involved. Much better to leave that to the customer!

Imagine the situation where a bookcase was placed needing one bracket into a wooden doorframe, the other into plasterboard, or brick. Potential for all kinds of diy mistakes!